# Use quote in csv module translation file

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I'm trying to translate a module strings, and use a quote in the translated text, tried this

```
"If the quote is approuved, simply click to ""proceed to checkout"" and follow steps online to confirm your order.","Si la soumission est approuvée, cliquez simplement sur ""accepter la soumission"" et suivez les étapes en ligne afin de confirmer votre commande."
```

But in the html email i got this

```
If the quote is approuved, simply click to ""proceed to checkout"
```

I tried to use

```
"Note: If you have a credit account established with us, you will have the choice to &quot;charge to the account&quot; during the payment step.","Note: Si vous avez un compte crédit d'établi avec nous, vous aurez le choix &quot;porter au compte&quot; lors de l'étape du paiement."
```

But, i got the quot; in the email message

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with:

In HTML template, i used '\' before the double quote

```
{{trans "Note: If you have a credit account established with us, you will have the choice to \"charge to the account\" during the payment step."}}
```

And in the i18 csv file, i used the double quotes ""

```
"Note: If you have a credit account established with us, you will have the choice to ""charge to the account"" during the payment step.","Note: Si vous avez un compte crédit d'établi avec nous, vous aurez le choix ""porter au compte"" lors de l'étape du paiement."
```

Answer (score 0):

In the file [vendor/magento/module-persistent/i18n/en_US.csv](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Persistent/i18n/en_US.csv)

You can see on line 9 :

`"Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping cart on this computer even if you are not signed in.","Check &quot;Remember Me&quot; to access your shopping cart on this computer even if you are not signed in."`

So try to use `&quot;`, your line should be :

`"If the quote is approuved, simply click to &quot;proceed to checkout&quot; and follow steps online to confirm your order.","Si la soumission est approuvée, cliquez simplement sur &quot;accepter la soumission&quot; et suivez les étapes en ligne afin de confirmer votre commande."`

Comment: I tried it, i got Si la soumission est approuvée, cliquez simplement sur &quot;accepter la soumission&quot; et suivez les étapes en ligne afin de confirmer votre commande.

It's a HTML mail template